# How to change the width of the ionic popover

Tags: ionic-framework, popover

I had created the ionic popup. Created a popover page and added action on button click to display popover from home page. but iam unable to change the width of the popover. below is the code;

**home.page.html:**

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-button expand="full" (click)="openPopover($Event)">Open popover</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

**home.page.ts:**

```js
async openPopover(ev: Event) {
 const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
   component:PopoverPage,
   componentProps: {
     custom_id: this.value
   },  
 });
 popover.present();    
}
```

**popover.page.html:**

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      this is popover
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item button color="danger" (click) = "closePopover()">
      <ion-icon name="close" slot="start"></ion-icon>
      Close Popover
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**popover.page.ts:**

```js
closePopover() {
  this.popoverController.dismiss();
}
```

please assist me how can i change the width of the popover as i tried adding custom  css to the ion-content of the popover page but its not working.

Answer (score 7):

**The other method did not work for me, these changes need to be made:**

First the `.contact-popover .popover-content{ width: 320px; }` content needs to be in `global.scss`

" This means that any custom styles need to go in a global stylesheet file. In an Ionic Angular starter this can be the src/global.scss file or you can register a new global style file by adding to the styles build option in angular.json."  ([says in documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover))

Second the CSS cannot be `width`, it needs to be `--width`. The custom css properties for this are at the bottom of this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover

Comment: Once again the absurdity of Ionic's use of the shadom dom strikes.They want self-contained lazy loaded components but they must be styled in the global stylesheet to work... ie not self-contained...

Answer (score 5):

For ionic 6.x the solution is

```
ion-popover {
  &::part(content) {
    min-width: 230px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a solution that applies to only one page and not the full web app?

Comment: yes (if I understand the question correctly). Just add a css class to your popover and use it in scss/css file

Comment: It does not work. I change first line for your code to ``.my-class ion-popover`` or ``.my-class`` and add the class to my popover and it is not working.

Comment: I think that you are doing smth wrong. First, please try to add this to app.scss. The second, this is wrong `.my-class ion-popover`

Answer (score 2):

two ways:

override the SCSS variables;

```
$popover-md-width: 320px; $popover-ios-width: 320px; $popover-wp-width: 320px;
```

or 2. give your popover a class:

```
let popover = this.popover.create(ContactPopover, {}, {cssClass: 'contact-popover'})
```

and then style the .popover-content:

```
.contact-popover .popover-content{ width: 320px; }

Ionic automatically calculates the correct position for your custom width popover.
```

Comment: thank you@Micha for your answer, but where exactly should i  need to put this line of code "let popover = this.popover.create(ContactPopover, {}, {cssClass: 'contact-popover'})"  in my code.

Comment: put the line
$popover-md-width: 320px; $popover-ios-width: 320px; $popover-wp-width: 320px;
in the popover.page.scss
to overwrite the existing style !

Comment: sorry I have no complete example running here, but what you can try last is to insert in scss-file
.custom-popover .popover-content{
    width: 90% !important;
    color: red;
};

Answer (score 2):

Ionic ^4 Popover width can be modified on a global level adding the following to the *styles.scss* file:

```css
ion-popover {
    --width: 320px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What has worked for me in ionic 6 is not to target the content but the host itself. After setting the cssClass option as previously answered like this:

```
this.popover.create(ContactPopover, {}, {cssClass: 'contact-popover'})
```

I added the equivalent in global.scss:

```
.contact-popover {
   --width: <custom width>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved adding a css class like this on the element in html, and then edit scss file, hope this will be useful for you.

```css
::ng-deep .wider-popover {
  --width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<ion-select [interfaceOptions]="{'cssClass': 'wider-popover'}"></ion-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add a class to an element property and then edit the scss in global.scss

```
.custom-popover {
  --width: 100%;
}
```

```
<ion-item class="text-center" lines="none">
  <ion-select interface="popover"[interfaceOptions]="customPopoverOptions">
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

```
 customPopoverOptions = {
    cssClass: 'custom-popover',
     animated: true,
  };
```

Comment: You need to write your answer in english

Comment: I changed the language